Zitadel Go API not working from non-localhost
I'm facing the issue that when I'm self hosting Zitadel and I try to connect to one of my APIs from a different ip than localhost, I suddenly cant get authorized.
I'm using the code from the Zitadel go backend tutorials.
I'm guessing this must be some type of cors issue, as the same curl command runs fine, if the tutorial app is connecting to zitadel on localhost, but it's not working like this:
var (
    // flags to be provided for running the example server
    domain = flag.String("domain", "192.168.41.151", "your ZITADEL instance domain (in the form: <instance>.zitadel.cloud or <yourdomain>)")
    key    = flag.String("key", "./267348118540921239.json", "path to your key.json")
    port   = flag.String("port", "8090", "port to run the server on (default is 8090)")

    // tasks are used to store an in-memory list used in the protected endpoint
    tasks []string
)

....curl:
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer vkpUuK_nrnqh_jwFI2CKUutbFO0k_ArT2gxkiECNQ40DgGqnKeWNKOt_ikY3ww83FRgbI0Y" http://localhost:8090/api/tasks
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 16 May 2024 08:27:07 GMT
Content-Length: 97

token introspection failed: http status not ok: 400 Bad Request {"error":"unauthorized_client"}

However, I cannot find any settings regarding to these settings within the Zitadel dashboard.

Have you configured CORS? Are you getting a CORS error in your browser's console? If so, what's the error message? Add it in your question (not as a picture but as text). For things to work cross-origin, you will at the very least need to ensure that request-header name Authorization is allowed in your CORS configuration.

I did not configure CORS anywhere, that was just a tip on my part what could cause this issue. I wanted to configure it in Zitadel, but there I could not find any related settings. My API works if it connects to zitadel on localhost, but doesnt work when it connects over 192.168.41.151. I'm not sure why the browser is necessary, it should work with the curl command as stated in the docs

Nevermind, the issue was not with Zitadel nor the Zitadel-Go package. It was caused by the fact that the time on the machine Zitadel was hosted from the time was behind a couple seconds, causing the token to be in the future on Zitadel's side
